# Solve for real numbers m and b, given functions f, g, and h, such that $h(x) = (1-x)\cdot g(x) + 2 = (2-x)\cdot f(x) - 1 = mx + b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If f, g, and g are functions, and m and b are real numbers such that
>   $$
> h(x) = (1-x)\cdot g(x) + 2 = (2-x)\cdot f(x) - 1 = mx + b,
> $$
>   for all $x$, find the values of $m$ and $b$.

**MY SOLUTION**

This seems to be a typical linear systems problem, and as so, I used a variety of variables to represent $mx + b$ for different functions, but whenever I try to eliminate variables, I have more variables than equations to eliminate with. Some help with this problem would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

**hint**

With $x=1$, we get

$$m+b=2=f(1)-1$$

and with $x=2$, it gives

$$2m+b=2-g(2)=-1$$

thus

$$m=-3  \text{  and  } \; b=5$$